# php xml_parser UTF-8 encoded values are split

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I am not sure if this is the correct behavior and how to effectively deal with it. I have defined an xml parser in php and it looks like this:

```
$xml_parser = xml_parser_create();
xml_parser_set_option($xml_parser, XML_OPTION_TARGET_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');
xml_parser_set_option($xml_parser,XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE,1);
xml_set_element_handler($xml_parser, "startElement", "endElement");
xml_set_character_data_handler($xml_parser, "characterData"); 
(....)   
function characterData($parser, $data){    print('<p>|' . $data . '|</p>');}
```

The input xml is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fields><field name="address"><value>aą</value></field></fields>
```

And the output looks like this:

```
|a|
|ą|
```

I was expecting it to look like this:

```
|aą|
```

Why does php split the UTF-8 encoded string into separate values??

Comment: I don't set it, it is passed to the callback function by the parser. Here is a description: http://php.net/manual/en/function.xml-set-character-data-handler.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xml-set-character-data-handler.php):

> It can be called multiple times inside each fragment (e.g. for non-ASCII strings).

Your code just needs to be able to handle that.